# Botón Next en KEYBOARD Android

Tags: android, xml

Tengo un formulario que estoy desarrollando en **Android Studio**, pretendo forzar al usuario para que solo escriba caracteres en Mayúsculas pero son varios campos los que debe recorrer en el formulario utilizando el `ScrollView`.

Algunas aplicaciones agregan en el **teclado** *Next* (siguiente), *Done* (finalizar) para saltar al siguiente `EditText`. Intente hacerlo pero simplemente no logro que funcione, no me muestra el botón en el **teclado**.

Este es el código **xml**.

```
    android:id="@+id/apmaterno"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
```

Comment: Agrega tu layout completo por favor. Tu problema es que no te muestra el boton "next"? o que no puedes cambiar de vista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trata agregando :

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

ó como otra opción, señala la siguiente vista a enfocar:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/SiguientView
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys, eres fantástica :D

Answer (score 2):

Pues funciona agregando esta linea siempre y cuando tu `EditText` no contenga muchos caracteres.

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

También puedes usar esta linea que sirve específicamente para agregar el **Siguiente** en el teclado.

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```